# passing data between jsp's using hidden fields

Tags: jsp

Struggling to transfer data between 2 jsp's.

jsp1  puts image_path (which contains uploads/Test.jpg) into webcamfile

```
document.getElementById("webcamfile").toString = image_path;
alert(document.getElementById("webcamfile").toString = image_path);
```

Then (actioned by a button in jsp1)

```
<form action="jsp2.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">
<input type="hidden" name="webcamfile" id="webcamfile" value=""/>
```

jsp2

```
String camera[] = request.getParameterValues("webcamfile"); System.out.println(camera);
```

I have also tried (with the appropriate config in jsp1)

```
String camera = String.valueOf (request.getParameter("webcamfile"));
String camera = request.getSession().getAttribute("webcamfile").toString();
String camera = request.getParameter("webcamfile").toString();
```

No attempt outputs anything, what am I doing wrong?

Even if I fix the value (in jsp1)

```
<input type="hidden" name="webcamfile" id="webcamfile" value="12345"/>
```

And then (in jsp2)

```
String camera[] = request.getParameterValues("webcamfile");                  
String camera2 = request.getParameter("webcamfile").toString();
String camera3 = String.valueOf (request.getParameter("webcamfile"));
String camera4 = request.getParameter("webcamfile");                    

System.out.println(camera);
System.out.println(camera2);
System.out.println(camera3);
System.out.println(camera4)
```

Nothing appears in the console.

The original intention was to pass a pathname to an image file -

```
var image_path = RegExp.$1;
var image_path = image_url.substring(image_url.indexOf("uploads", 8));
alert(image_path);
```

The pathname (in image_path) is uploads/Test.jpg

But just doing the following In preparation for transfer) puts a numerical value in place of uploads (which I dont want, I want uploads/Test.jpg)

```
document.getElementById("webcamfile").value = image_path;
```

Ater some fiddling I managed to get an iterator to work (this outputs 12345)

```
if (itemx.getFieldName().equals("webcamfile"))
{
webcamfile=itemx.getString();
```

So, how to I get either image_path or webcamfile (which I assume are strings) into the value= bit?

```
<input type="hidden" name="webcamfile" id="webcamfile" value=""/>
```

Regards
Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsp2.jsp use following code to get value:

**${pageContext.request.getParameter("nextData")}**

Check more on pageContext http://www.javatpoint.com/pageContext-implicit-object

Comment: can you post code how you used it? Post the code of jsp2.jsp.

Comment: any progress with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this line: `document.getElementById("webcamfile").toString =  image_path;`.
You should change toString with value, so: `document.getElementById("webcamfile").value =  image_path;`

Comment: Thanks @Pez_93, though despite the change nothing seems to be transferred to jsp2 (none of my 3 System.out lines produces anything in the console)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on with your code for passing data from one jsp to another:

- Your JS is getting an element but not the value of the element document.getElementById("webcamfile").value
- Your JSP input type is hidden with an empty value, am not sure you want your value to be fixed (if so give a value here and no need in the JS since its hidden) or generated (You could generate from the server Java or client using JS remember set the value)

To pass data From one JSP to The next you can either:

- Make a form as you have with an input user can specify or empty with a fixed
  value
- Everything passing from HTML/JSP is String type so
  there is no need to parse it to a different type just simply
  request.getParameter("webcamfile") is enough to give you a string
- Add a checking to determine the string value is either null or empty to be more precise

All the best.

Comment: Thanks @Al-Kathiri Khalid, though even if I fix the value (see my edited post) still nothing seems to be transfered or output to console.

Comment: Yes ofcourse remove enctype="multipart/form-data" that for transferring data and js listener onSubmit, now looking at your code: <input type="hidden" name="webcamfile" id="webcamfile" value="12345"/> we expecting 123 then String camera4 = request.getParameter("webcamfile");  should work

Comment: Removing the enctype throws a javaException

Comment: I won't understand your code unless you post the whole code or at least the log for the exception type and cause. Just for clarification you want to pass what kind of data type a whole file (data) or a reference to a file (String)?

Comment: I have modified my original post, I get an iterator to work and I can now transfer 12345 to jsp2. How do I get the image_path or webcamfile string variable into that command line (instead of 12345). Regards Active.